# Probability about die

Tags: probability

I have a die, I roll it $9$ times, what is the probability I get all six numbers at least once?

I tried solving this by finding the probability that I don't get all numbers at least once, then subtract it from one, so I did:

$$1-(P(\neg1)+P(\neg2)+P(\neg3)+\dotsm)$$

but my answer is wrong.

Comment: This is a [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.  But you need to apply PIE to avoid over counting.

$1-(P(¬1)+P(¬2)+\cdots+ P(¬6))$ does not take into consideration cases where you roll no `1` *and* no `2`.

---

The event of getting all six numbers at least once *is* the complement of the event of not getting any of *at least* one number.

To obtain the probability of that: we count the ways to select 1 to 5 of the numbers, multiplied by the probability of not obtaining them, and *add and subtract* these values using the **Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion**.

Then subtract it all from $1$, because that was the complement of the event we require.  In short:

$$1-{6\choose 1}(\tfrac 5 6)^9 + {6\choose 2}(\tfrac 4 6)^9 - {6\choose 3}(\tfrac 3 6)^9+{6\choose 4}(\tfrac 2 6)^9- {6\choose 5}(\tfrac 1 6)^9$$